# Parse PFUser data not updated on iPhone Simulator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, parse-platform, parse-server

For some reason the user data is never updated when testing my app on the simulator. For example, the value for the object "age" can have been changed to 22, but the simulator behaves as if it was still 21. Would anyone know if it's just a simulator issue, and would run differently on a phone? My iPhone's screen is completely broken, so I am unable to test it right now.

Comment: I'm having same issue on a real device.

Comment: @GellertLee Do you think it's a Parse issue then?

Comment: @Dups Do you update the data on the phone or on the server ?

Comment: @JulienKode Comment ça? Genre si c'est fait à travers le code ou manuellement?

Comment: @Dups Tu met a jours les données coté client ou sur le serveur ? / Do you update data in client side or server side ?

Comment: @JulienKode Je dirais serveur, parce que le client déclenches une fonction cloud code.

Comment: @Dups Je pense que tu dois mettre à jour les données coté client / I think you should update data in the client side

[See](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43749480/parse-pfuser-data-not-updated-on-iphone-simulator/43763227#43763227)

Comment: @Dups si tu veux plus d'exemple hésite pas :)

Comment: @JulienKode merci beaucoup! Je vais essayer ta méthode, et te tenir au courant!

Comment: @Dups Perfect 

Comment: @JulienKode Salut j'ai pas encore pu l'essayer, comme par hasard mon disque avec le project Xcode avait arrêté de fonctionner. Je vais essayer ta méthode tout a l'heure, et te tenir au courant. Cette fois pour de vrai! haha

Comment: @Dups Merci pour l'info et de me tenir au courant  bon test

Comment: @JulienKode Salut ça ne marche toujours pas, enfin, je ne sais pas exactement comment l'implementer. J'aimerais l'insérer dans un PFQuery.

Comment: @Dups C'est possible de me montré le code ?

Comment: `guard let myUser = PFUser.currentUser() else { return } // Get the current user
do{ let data = try myUser.objectForKey("chargeID")?.fetch()
try chargeID = data! as! String
}catch{}`

Comment: @Dups ce code est donc dans un block après un find d'une query ?

Comment: @JulienKode oui c'était ça à la base, mais j'ai mis ça dans sa propre fonction maintenant `func getChargeID()`, mais le résultat est le même.

Comment: @JulienKode ok ça marche

Answer (score 0):

In Parse, [PFUser](http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/api/Classes/PFUser.html) is a subclass of [PFObject](http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/api/Classes/PFObject.html), to update a [PFObject](http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/api/Classes/PFObject.html) in the [Parse iOS SDK](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX) you have many ways to do that

There are 2 popular methods:

- [fetch](http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/api/Categories/PFObject(Synchronous).html#/c:objc(cs)PFObject(im)fetch) to update your object [synchronously](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programmation_synchrone)
- [fetchInBackground](http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/api/Classes/PFObject.html#/c:objc(cs)PFObject(im)fetchInBackground) to update your object [asynchronously](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchrony_(computer_programming))

For example with [fetch](http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/api/Categories/PFObject(Synchronous).html#/c:objc(cs)PFObject(im)fetch):

```
guard let myUser = PFUser.current() else { return } // Get the current user
do {
try myUser.fetch()
} catch {
  print("Error when fetching the new data")
}
```

For example with [fetchInBackground](http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/api/Classes/PFObject.html#/c:objc(cs)PFObject(im)fetchInBackground):

```
guard let myUser = PFUser.current() else { return } // Get the current user
myUser.fetchInBackground()
```

You can also use closure with [fetchInBackgroundWithBlock](http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/api/Classes/PFObject.html#/c:objc(cs)PFObject(im)fetchInBackgroundWithBlock:)